# Call laravel controller from vue file

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, axios

I created a component in vue file and I want to fetch data from laravel controller function. 
Currently, I have used axios to fetch data. But can I directly call laravel controller function?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are doing right. Calling directly the controller from blade or vue is not a good practice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, the only way to communicate with your laravel app is your **web service**. ( Ex: REST Api )

Because **Laravel** and **Vuejs** are completely separated.
Although in using web services you would have different methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. Expose a route from Laravel/Lumen app
2. Call the route or url from vue using any http client(axios)

N.B: You cann't call the controller method on Laravel app directly from your Vue CLI

Answer (score 0):

You need to do few steps.

in vue js file script area

```
const url = `https://www.naveedramzan.com/api/getData/users/4`;
Axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${params.token}`; // if you are using some token authentication
Axios.get(url,{params: params})
     .then((response) => {
         res(response.data);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
         rej(err);
     });
```

In laravel, routes/api.php file

```
Route::post('getData/users', 'UsersController@getData');
```

In laravel, the controller file

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


public function getData(Request $request){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pacakge

```
composer require yudhees/laravel-vue-controller
```

By Installing this pacakge You can access your laravel controller within your vue file without writing any seperate api ,
By using this package You need to send your controller path and function name
and also if the functions needs any params you can send this also .

for More detailed Information [Vist here](https://github.com/yudhees/laravel-vue-controller/)